# How tow compare current cell with previous cell on a CSV file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several CSV files. I want to check if the Time has passed from 600 in each file take the value of X in a certain row and make a list, then plot the list.

Each CSV file is like this:

[image: each CSV file is like this]

what can I do? I am learning using python with pandas.
Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Set path to the folder containing the .csv files
PATH = 'Folder path' 

### Fetch all files in path
fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)
print(fileNames)

### Filter file name list for files ending with .csv
fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]
### Loop over all files
for file in fileNames:

### Read .csv file and append to list
df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, usecols=['Time','x'])
    ### Compare rows
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.ix[index, 'Time'] <1000 and df.ix[index - 1, 'Time']>1000:
            return (data.ix[index, 'x'])
```

Comment: First, produce a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think the indexing might help u...

u can do something like..

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

yr_index = 2 #row number (remember rows start from 0 not 1)
col_no = 2#the index value of the column name eg A ->0 C->2
this_cell = df.iloc[yr_index ][col_no]
prev_cell = df.iloc[yr_index -1][col_no]
if this_cell  != prev_cell:
    #do what ever u want
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quicker to create a second dataframe shifted by 1 cell, using [pd.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) rather than iterating through every cell.

For example, instead of the loop, you could do

```
df_shifted = pd.shift(df, -1)
```

Get the indices where your conditions hold with

```
idx = ((df[['Time']] < 1000) & (df_shifted[['Time']] > 1000)).values
```

Then you can filter your original dataframe using

```
df_filtered = df[idx]['x']
```